# Como puedo extraer un dato que va cambiando y se guarde un excel o txt?

Tags: python, selenium

En este código el email se ingresa desde una base de datos en Excel, luego se carga en una web para validar el correo y lo que necesito es que el dato o respuesta que me genera luego de ingresar el correo se copie a un Excel y siga hasta terminar con los 50 correos respectivamente.

```
filesheet = r"C:\Users\SOPORTE\Documents\Libro1.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filesheet)
hojas = wb.get_sheet_names()
print(hojas)

numeros = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
wb.close() 

for i in range(2,50):
   fil1, fil2, fil3 = numeros[f'A{i}:C{i}'][0]
   print(fil1.value)
   time.sleep(2)
   driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys(str(fil1.value))
   time.sleep(3)
```

No se si guardarlo en un Excel o text, pero necesitaría que se almacene en uno de esos ya creado anteriormente talvez.
Trate de conseguir el valor o texto que me da luego del correo pero no me sirve, es este:

```
resultado = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
resultado = resultado.text
print(resultado)
```

Con el código anterior solo me imprime los números de la base de datos, no logra extraer el contenido web de la página.
Si alguien sabe como lo puedo hacer gracias. Estoy usando Selenium.

Esta es la sección html de la que necesito sacar o extraer la data:

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext _55r1 inputtext _1kbt inputtext _1kbt" name="email" id="email" tabindex="0" placeholder="Correo electrónico o número de teléfono" value autofocus="1" autocomplete="username" aria-label="Correo electrónico o número de teléfono">
```

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el (Recorrido de bienvenida)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: el codigo debe subirse como texto, no como imagenes. Te recomiendo leer [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y [ask].

Comment: probablemente el resultado que deseas guardar no se encuentra bajo el ID "email". podrías mostrar el trozo de código html generado en la respuesta?